# Why must I click twice on an <a> to get jQuery to change it's CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have this jQuery code currently:

```
$('.chooser .options > li').on('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML)
});

$('.chooser .toggle').on('click', function (e) {

    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility == "hidden") ? "visible" : "hidden";

    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.opacity = (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.opacity == "0") ? "1" : "0";

});
```

This is triggered by an `<a>` element.  However, if you click once on the anchor, it does nothing.  Click twice, and the CSS is changed.  Why is this, and how can I fix it?  I'm thinking it has something to do with changing the style sheet.

### http://jsfiddle.net/Godisgood/03vc88r7/2/

```js
$('.chooser .options > li').on('click', function(e) {
  alert(e.target.innerHTML)
});

$('.chooser .toggle').on('click', function(e) {

  e.target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility == "hidden") ? "visible" : "hidden";

  e.target.nextElementSibling.style.opacity = (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.opacity == "0") ? "1" : "0";

});
```

```css
.chooser {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
.container {} .options {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 2s;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chooser container"><a class="chooser toggle">__</a>

    <ul class="chooser options">
      <li>christian</li>
      <li>homeschooler</li>
      <li>family</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. not totally sure, but I would recommend doing it this way

http://jsfiddle.net/03vc88r7/5/

**CSS**

```
.chooser {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
}
.options {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.visible {
    opacity:1;
    visibility: visible;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.chooser .options > li').on('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML)
});

$('.chooser .toggle').on('click', function (e) {

    if($('.options').hasClass('visible')){
        $('.options').removeClass('visible');
    }else{
         $('.options').addClass('visible');   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are retrieving the element's "style" attribute.  Initially this is empty.  What I think has happened is that you have applied a CSS class to your element and believed that set the "style" attribute of an element.  It didn't.

When you create an element, that element has CSS properties applied to it.  Those properties can come through:

- inheritance from a parent
- application of a named class
- explicit setting from the `style` attribute of the element

When you query an element's `style` attribute, what you get is what was explicitly set through a previous application of `style` and not related to the CSS properties in effect on the element through the other mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
e.target.nextElementSibling.style.visibility = 
(window.getComputedStyle(e.target.nextElementSibling).visibility == "hidden") ? "visible" : "hidden";

e.target.nextElementSibling.style.opacity = 
(window.getComputedStyle(e.target.nextElementSibling).opacity == "0") ? "1" : "0";
```

`.style` on a dom node returns the inline style for the element; since you're applying the initial styling with a stylesheet, you need to look at the computed style instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use **getComputedStyle** method to get the current styles applied to the element:

```
$('.chooser .options > li').on('click', function (e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML)
});

$('.chooser .toggle').on('click', function (e) {


    var styles = e.target.nextElementSibling.style;
    var computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(e.target.nextElementSibling, null);

    styles.visibility = computedStyles.visibility == "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden";
    styles.opacity = computedStyles.opacity == '0' ? '1' : '0';



});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/03vc88r7/4/